# Working on developing an inventory app. I'm trying to save multiple objects in realm

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, realm

Working on an inventory application. The first view controller is a table view of all the sites. The user is able to add locations to the table. The list will display the "location name" and the "location address". Once the user clicks on an item in the tableview they have 4 different categories they can choose to upload inventory for the site. For instance:

Location Name : Corporate office
Location Address: New York, NY

Inventory options
1. Cleaning products
2. Tools
3. Electrical
4. Appliances

I'm trying to figure out how to layout the realm objects to hold the data for the sites chosen. I understand "list" is for relationships but still trying to get a hold of it. Please see my realm code below.

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Location: Object {

    dynamic var siteName = ""
    dynamic var siteAddress: String? = nil 
}


class ApplianceLocation: Object {

    dynamic var itemName: String = ""
    dynamic var quantity: Int = 0

    let siteInfo = List<Location>()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current model would allow that the same appliance has multiple locations and it occurs in all these locations in the same quantity. I don't think that this describes pretty well how appliance's behave in reality.

So assuming that an appliance, but also other items, can occur independently on different locations in different quantities, a model with minor changes like seen below is already suitable to describe that:

```
class Location: Object {    
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var address: String? = nil

    // Note: This is read-only. But it might become helpful
    // to navigate your model.
    var appliances: [Appliance] {
         return linkingObjects(Appliance.self, forProperty: "location")
    }
}

class Appliance: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var quantity: Int = 0
    dynamic var location: Location? // just a single location
}
```

But this has the disadvantage that you would need to use backlinks to navigate from a location to all appliances which are placed there. Backlinks offer still not as much convenience as links in the direction in which they are defined. (Note: This is on our to-do list and will be addressed in the near future.)
So for now let's try to invert the direction of the definition.

```
class Location: Object {    
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var address: String? = nil
    let appliances = List<Appliance>()
}

class Appliance: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var quantity: Int = 0
    var location: Location? {
         return linkingObjects(Location.self, forProperty: "appliances").first
    }
}
```

Okay, but what if we want to add now the other categories as well?
You could just add for each of them another independent `Object` class and a to-many link from `Location`.

```
class Location: Object {    
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var address: String? = nil
    let appliances = List<Appliance>()
    let cleaningProducts = List<CleaningProduct>()
    let tools = List<Tool>()
    // …
}

class CleaningProduct: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var quantity: Int = 0
    var location: Location? {
         return linkingObjects(Location.self, forProperty: "cleaningProducts").first
    }
}
```

But then you would duplicate a lot of code, which makes it harder to maintain your model and less flexible to changes.
First idea might be to use inheritance and introduce an intermediate `Object` subclass `Item`, which defines the properties `name` and `quantity`.
But while Realm supports a form of inheritance mapping in general, it doesn't support polymorphic relations yet, so that isn't really an option here.
An alternative might be to get rid of all specific category subclasses and generalize them on one `Item` class, which links to a category. This works especially well if there are no additional properties to store, which differentiates a `CleaningProduct` from an `Appliance` from a `Tool`.

```
class Location: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var address: String? = nil
    let items = List<Item>()
}

class Category: Object {
    /// e.g. Cleaning products, Tools, …
    dynamic var name = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "name"
    }
}

class Item: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var quantity: Int = 0
    dynamic var category: Category?
    var location: Location? {
         return linkingObjects(Location.self, forProperty: "location").first
    }
}
```

#### Creating Objects

The following code shows how you can create objects for the last proposed model.

```
let realm = try! Realm()

// Create all our categories
let categoryNames = ["Cleaning Product", "Tools", "Electrical", "Appliance"]
try! realm.write {
for categoryName in categoryNames {    
    realm.create(Category.self, value: [ name: categoryName], update: true)  
}

// Add a first location
let loc1 = Location()
loc1.name = "ABC office"
loc1.address = "Infinite Loop 2, Cupertino, CA"
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(loc1)
}
print(loc1.items.count) // => 0

// Add an appliance to the just created location
let item1 = Item()
item1.name = "Vacuum cleaner"
item1.category = realm.objects(Category).filter("name = ?", "Appliance").first!
try! realm.write {
    loc1.items.add(item1)
}
print(loc1.items.count) // => 1

// Add a new location
let loc2 = Location()
loc2.name = "ABC office #2"
loc2.address = "1338 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, CA"
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(loc2)
}
print(loc2.items.count) // => 0
```

Comment: WOW so much info. Thanks for your help. Going to try this out and let you know!

Comment: How would you go about saving these objects. right now if i create a location for example "ABC office". I add an appliance to "ABC office", when i go to add another location in my main tableview. That location also see's the previous item created under "ABC office".

Comment: I guess that happens with the model in your question when you add the newly created location to the `siteInfo`? I updated my answer with an example, how you can add objects for the last proposed model.

Comment: Marius i really appreciate your help. I'm developing my first app for iOS and hope to get it finished by the end of this month. I've studied swift for the past 8 months. I tried core data and it was a complete nightmare. Realm seems so much easier to understand but still working on grasping relationships. Do you know of any documentation besides whats on the realm site that I can read up on? Once again thanks for your insight.

Comment: Glad I could help! Well, we're trying to constantly improve our docs and are rethinking them currently a bit. There are some further tutorials linked in https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-recipes and especially the featured components on https://realm.io/addons/ might give you a better idea how to tackle something when trying to understand how they tackle frequent problems in a generically manner. Let us know if you're missing anything in particular.

Comment: Hey Marius sorry to be a pain. The code you showed me details information if I force that info into the app. I want the user to input the data. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: i ended up going back to Core Data. Was able to get it all sorted out with NSFetch request.